# Printing array info

Tags: php

I have a method that takes 3 arrays as arguments, then creates an array based on values from the 3 arrays passed through. This info is then sent to an email method that sends it off. It has worked fine until now. The problem is my key-value pairing. Some of the values are not printing and I'm not sure why. I have omitted unrelated code for illustration purposes. Take a look...

```
public function SendToISS($user,$questions,$scores_translated) {    

    $userinfo = array("First Name:"=>$user['first'],
                      "Last Name:"=>$user['last'],
                    "Organization:"=>$user['org'],
                      "State:"=>$user['state'],
                      "Zip:"=>$user['zip'],
                    "Phone:"=>$user['phone'],
                    "Email:"=>$user['email'],
                    ""=>"",

                    "Assessment Answers:"=>"",

                    "Assessment One:"=>$questions[0],
                    "&nbsp;&nbsp;".$user['first']."'s Answer:"=>$scores_translated[0],

                    "Assessment Two:"=>$questions[1],
                    "&nbsp;&nbsp;".$user['first']."'s Answer:"=>$scores_translated[1],

                    "Assessment Three:"=>$questions[2],
                    "&nbsp;&nbsp;".$user['first']."'s Answer:"=>$scores_translated[2],

                    "Assessment Four:"=>$questions[3],
                    "&nbsp;&nbsp;".$user['first']."'s Answer:"=>$scores_translated[3],

                    "Assessment Five:"=>$questions[4],
                    "&nbsp;&nbsp;".$user['first']."'s Answer:"=>$scores_translated[4]
                    );

}
```

This is the result in my email box. The scores_translated array is only printing the first value, then stopping.

```
 First Name: Steven
 Last Name: Pepe
 Organization: Laerdal
 State: New York
 Zip: 12590
 Phone: 8452977770
 Email: steven.pepe@laerdal.com

 Assessment Answers: 
 Assessment One: Administer multiple assessments of student progress throughout the class.
  Steven's Answer: The program does not perform this strategy.
 Assessment Two: Establish a passing standard for psychomotor and critical thinking skills that is above the minimum competency level.
 Assessment Three: The program does not perform this strategy.
 Assessment Four: Assure instructional consistency when preparing students for the NREMT-B exam.
 Assessment Five: Provide immediate feedback for written, practical evaluations to students.
```

Comment: Please specify _what_ is missing.

Comment: @SergiuParaschiv I would expect to see "Steven's Answer:" once for each question.  I don't, and can't immediately see why that's not being printed.

Comment: What is missing is the rest of the key-value pairs after "Assessment One:". They should also contain the scores. You can see this in the email results.

Comment: @zebediah49, yes, that is the problem. Nothing unusual in the array, it is identical to the $questions array.

Comment: Here's a hint, if it helps. If I omit the questions, then all 5 answers print.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to be using identical keys for the same thing.  That is, you use `"&nbsp;&nbsp;".$user['first']."'s Answer:"` as a key for five different things, and are just overwriting rather than appending.  I'm not sure why this used to work in the first place.

Try switching to something like `"&nbsp;&nbsp;".$user['first']."'s Answer #1:"`, and numbering them, to see if that fixes it.

Comment: It's always something right under your nose sometimes. Thanks. That was it.

Answer (score 1):

Your key's are not unique. This is the key that you are using in your array and it can only be set once `"&nbsp;&nbsp;".$user['first']."'s Answer:"`

You need something like `"&nbsp;&nbsp;".$user['first']."'s Answer One:"` for the keys to the responses

Comment: We appear to have posted identical answers, seven seconds apart.